# MSDeploy with sql script

Tags: sql, msdeploy

I have a deployment package that needs to run against about 3 different enviroments.

I want to specify a sql script to run (source) with the enviroments database (destiniation).

I don't want to specify the connection string in the deploy script because it contains sql login info.

I would like to be able to read a setting from the destination for the connection string.

Can I mark this a parameter to be specified when unpackaging the deployment package on the server? If so, how so I use the parameter in the dest:sql="connection string"?

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Guthrie has a pretty good write up on [this sort of thing here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx).  He specifically mentions the changing of parameters both in prompts for the admin and in an automated fashion via the command line within deployment and/or automation scripts.